# SQL Server 2012: update column with 2 columns concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 columns in a table :[CatId], [ItemId]

CatId is 4 digits and ItemId is 1 or 2. What I want to achieve is to replace the ItemId with the concatenation [CatId]+[ItemId] , but if ItemId is 1 digit then add a 0.

For example:

`CatId: 1555, ItemId: 12 -> ItemId: 155512`

`CatId: 1555, ItemId: 2 -> ItemId: 155502`

Comment: Your sample and your description do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as

```
select cast(catId as int) * 100 + cast(itemid as int)
```

If you want this as a string:

```
select cast(cast(catId as int) * 100 + cast(itemid as int) as varchar(255))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *update* your table then try this option:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET ItemId = CatId + RIGHT('00' + ItemId, 2);
```

This assumes that the `CatId` and `ItemId` columns are text and not numbers.  If they be numeric, then see Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [CatId] [char](4) NULL,
    [ItemId] [char](2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


Insert Data 

USE [ABC]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([CatId] ,[ItemId]) VALUES ('1231','1')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([CatId] ,[ItemId]) VALUES ('1232','2')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([CatId] ,[ItemId]) VALUES ('1233','10')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([CatId] ,[ItemId]) VALUES ('1234','23')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([CatId] ,[ItemId]) VALUES ('1237','6')

Select  [CatId]+     (Case  WHEN len(ItemId)  =1 THEN '0'+[ItemId]  ELSE [ItemId]  END  ) as DATA  from [dbo].[Test]

**Result** 
DATA
123101 
123202 
123310
123423
123706
```